# Concurrency Issues when multiple users uses Portal (MySQL and PHP)

Tags: mysql, myisam, php

We have set up a portal using Yii Framework in Apache, PHP and MySQL. In the portal, there is a feature to export the data in dbf format, the extract takes around 7 minutes, but in those 7 minutes no other user can do anything in portal, not even login.

All tables are in MyISAM Engine.

I cannot provide you the link as its in our internal server.

Server is 4core Xeon Processor with 32 GB Ram.

Answer (score -1):

The framework calls somewhere, somehow the command `mysqldump`, and there you need to give him the `--lock-tables=false` option.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, but that didn't work. currently mysqldump config is as below:

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M
lock-tables=false

Comment: Hi, I found the root cause for this, its because we are using the same yiibase for all portals for different countries, but thanks for the lock table suggestion, it helped me a little in performance :)